# better way to access a constant string from a controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, model-view-controller

I have a constant string defined at the top of controller like below. I want to access this string in one of the condition I check in the view to see if the value matches the string value. I thought to hard code the value in cshtml in the condition, but curious is there a better way to do? (I know ViewBag/ViewData/TempData) but when I write any of these at top of controller, its not being recognized. I dont know how to write too. Or any other better way? Please help. We do use Viewbag in some cshtml however those data are written in view and accessed in another view.

**Controller**

```
private const string FundType = "Super"
```

**Razor cshtml page**

```
@if (Model.IsMember && Model.New && Model.Type.Fund != "Super")
```

Comment: Is that constant only used inside single controller or shared across multiple/all controllers? If the latter is what you want, you can use web.config's `appSettings` key and call it in controller with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SettingsKeyName"]`.

Comment: Well, `ViewData` and `ViewBag` have their life-cycle attached to per request means they will only live as long as the request is alive. So, it if you can manage to assign the property to a class and then refer that class in the view you will be able to access it or else you have to pass it to `ViewBag`/`ViewData` on every request or you can assign that value to `TempData` on the controller's `index()` with `TempData.keep()` so it is available throughout all the controller's reqeust.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: Good one, but how do we call that in the view? As per my request in the view I compare

Answer (score 2):

You may extract that to a separate class where you can store this string constant values.

```
public class FundType
{
    public const string Super = "Super";
    public const string NonSuper = "NonSuper";
}
```

Now you can use this in your razor views

```
@if (Model.IsMember && Model.New && Model?.Type?.Fund != FundType.Super)
{
   <p>Inside If </p>
}
```

Or in controller code

```
var vm = new YourViewModel();
vm.Type.Fund = FundType.Super;  // Assuming Type is not null
```

If you are defining the class inside a different namespace, make sure to use the needed `using YourNamespace` when using this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your string to the view as a Model like below:

```
private const string FundType = "Super"
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View((object)FundType);
}
```

Here, (object) bit is important so that the MVC doesnt try to load the constant as a Viewname. In your view, you can then access it like below:

```
@model constString
<span>Fund is: @Model</span> <!-- Output is Super -->
```